# Fortran command-line arguments

Tags: command-line, fortran

In g++ I was using `getopt_long` to handle command-line options. Does there
exist the same thing for [Gfortran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gfortran)?

I want to be able to pass aguments to some Fortran unit tests.

Currently I have the following. As one can notice I am taking care
of getting the key and value myself. When using C++ getopt_long
was doing this for me.

```
i = 1

Do

Call Get_command_argument (i, arg)
If (Len_trim (arg) == 0) Exit

pos = Index (arg, "=")

!!$ Long option argument.
If (arg(1:2) == "--") Then
  If (pos == 0) Then
    c = arg
    val = ""
  Else
    c = arg(:pos-1)
    val = arg(pos+1:)
  End If

!!$ Short option argument.
Elseif (arg(1:1) == "-") Then
  c = arg
  val = arg(pos+1:)

!!$ Non option argument.
Else
  c = arg
  val = arg

End If

!!$------------------------------------------------------------ 

Select Case (c)

  Case ("-b","--brief")
    arg_brief = .True.

  Case ("-h","--help")
    arg_help = .True.

  Case ("-v","-V","--version")
    arg_version = .True.

  ! Output model geographical definition
  Case ("-cunit")
    arg_cunit = val

  Case default
    arg_nonopt = Trim (Adjustl (arg))
    Write (*,*) "Warning: Non option argument"

End Select

i = i + 1

End Do

!!$-------------------------------------------------------------

!!$ [TODO] Get numbers from arg_cunit

If (arg_cunit .contains. "-") Then

  If (arg_cunit .contains. ",") Then
    !!$ "-" and "," are present.

  Else
    !!$ "-" only are present. 

  End If

Else If (arg_cunit .contains. ",") Then
  !!$ "," only are present

End If
```

Comment: From your comment below, may I suggest that you make the _parsing_ aspect a lot more explicit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can use `GET_COMMAND_ARGUMENT` as you already do but that is the easy part. The hard part of the problem is to fill your variables with various numerical, logical and string values according to those argument strings. That is what the the following does:

One can use a namelist for easy argument parsing. Just add the begin and end markers. It is not too flexible, though, but very simple!

A (very!) short google search for `getopt` reveals a couple of Fortran ports of this library (or similar ones which include parsing):

http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/getopt_long_module

http://www.dominik-epple.de/getoptions/

http://lagrange.mechse.illinois.edu/partmc/partmc-2.4.0/doc/html/getopt_8_f90_source.html

and

http://libsufr.sourceforge.net/doxygen/getopt_8f90_source.html (thanks to AstroFloyd)

Comment: I didn't get the first option to compile, the second has short options only and the third no longer exists.  I created a getopt module for Fortran containing getopt()/getopt_long()-functions in libSUFR v0.7.3: http://libsufr.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Updated the third one, thanks for the notice. Just had to find a new version, but it was easy.

Answer (score 7):

Look at `COMMAND_ARGUMENT_COUNT` and `GET_COMMAND_ARGUMENT`.   e.g., in the gfortran manual.  They are standard Fortran intrinsics.

Comment: I know about them. Are there others? When I use `GET_COMMAND_ARGUMENT`, I have to take care ofparsing short and long options myself.

Comment: The point of the libraries is not just to get the argument strings, but to parse them and assign the values to numerical and other variables.